# How to sort an associative array in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, oracle10g

I have an associative array like this:

```
continent_population('Australia') := 30;
continent_population('Antarctica') := 90;
continent_population('UK') := 50;
```

How do I sort this array after values in PL/SQL? Thanks!

Comment: What would a sorted associative array look like?  Would the key 'Australia' still be associated with the number 30?  If so, what would the difference be between a sorted and an unsorted associative array?

Comment: I want this array to be sorted because I need to display every value in ASC order, but still keep the correlation between the key and value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't sort an associative array by values, but you have to convert the data to some other data structure and make the sorting there. The easiest way would have been to convert to another associative array where keys and values swap places, but that requires your key values should be unique too.

Below is an example adapted to your case from [Sorting PL/SQL Collections](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/31/sorting-plsql-collections-the-quite-simple-way-part-two-have-the-sql-engine-do-the-heavy-lifting/). Please check that article for the details.

```
/* The sorting is done with SQL thus these types have to be SQL types. */

create type sortable_t is object(
  continent varchar2(32767),
  population number
);
/

create type sortable_table_t is table of sortable_t;
/

declare
  type continent_population_t is table of pls_integer index by varchar2(32767);
  continent_population continent_population_t;

  i varchar2(32767);

  sorted sortable_table_t := sortable_table_t();
begin
  /* Populate original data. */

  continent_population('Australia') := 30;
  continent_population('Antarctica') := 90;
  continent_population('UK') := 50;
  continent_population('USA') := 50;

  /* Convert to a helper data type that is used for sorting. */

  i := continent_population.first;

  while i is not null loop
    sorted.extend(1);
    sorted(sorted.last) := new sortable_t(i, continent_population(i));
    i := continent_population.next(i);
  end loop;

  /* Show that the content is not sorted yet. */

  dbms_output.put_line('Unsorted:');
  for j in sorted.first .. sorted.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(sorted(j).continent || ' = ' || sorted(j).population);
  end loop;

  /* Sorting with SQL. */

  select cast(multiset(select *
                       from table(sorted)
                       order by 2 asc, 1 asc)
              as sortable_table_t)
    into sorted
    from dual;

  /* Show that the content is now sorted. */

  dbms_output.put_line('Sorted by value:');
  for j in sorted.first .. sorted.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(sorted(j).continent || ' = ' || sorted(j).population);
  end loop;

end;
/
```

Prints:

```
Unsorted:
Antarctica = 90
Australia = 30
UK = 50
USA = 50
Sorted by value:
Australia = 30
UK = 50
USA = 50
Antarctica = 90
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated. Since Oracle 12c, querying associative arrays using the TABLE operator is possible, as long as the type is declared in a package spec: https://galobalda.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/new-in-oracle-12c-querying-an-associative-array-in-plsql-programs/

You **can** sort an associative array by values, and you **don't have** to convert the data:
[Sorting an index-by table (associative array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559722/sorting-an-index-by-table-associative-array/58561711#58561711)