# What data structure to use in order to sort this data in PL/SQL?

Tags: arrays, oracle, sorting, plsql, oracle11g

This is Oracle 11.2g. In a PL/SQL function, I've got a loop whereby each iteration, I create a string and an integer associated with that string. The function returns the final concatenation of all the generated strings, sorted (depending on a function input parameter), either alphabetically or by the value of the integer. To give an idea, I'm generating something like this:

```
Iteration String Integer
        1 Oslo        40
        2 Berlin      74
        3 Rome        25
        4 Paris       10
```

If the input parameter says to sort alphabetically, the function output should look like this :

```
Berlin, Oslo, Paris, Rome
```

Otherwise, we return the concatenated strings sorted by the value of the associated integer:

```
Paris, Rome, Oslo, Berlin
```

What is the most appropriate data structure to achieve this sort? I've looked at collections, associative arrays and even varrays. I've been kind of shocked how difficult this seems to be to achieve in Oracle. I saw this question but it doesn't work in my case, as I need to be able to sort by both index and value: [How to sort an associative array in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800880/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-in-pl-sql) Is there a more appropriate data structure for this scenario, and how would you sort it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very easy if you use PL/SQL as SQL and not like other languages. It is quite specific and sometimes is very nice exactly because of that.

Sometimes I really hate PL/SQL, but this case is absolutely about love.

See how easy it is:

```
create type it as object (
  iter          number,
  stringval     varchar2(100),
  intval        integer
);

create type t_it as table of it;

declare
  t       t_it := new t_it();
  tmp1    varchar2(32767);
  tmp2    varchar2(32767);
begin
  t.extend(4);
  t(1) := new it(1,'Oslo',40);
  t(2) := new it(2,'Berlin',74);
  t(3) := new it(3,'Rome',25);
  t(4) := new it(4,'Paris',10);

  select listagg(stringval,', ') within group (order by stringval),
         listagg(stringval,', ') within group (order by intval)
  into tmp1, tmp2
  from table(t);

  dbms_output.put_line(tmp1);
  dbms_output.put_line(tmp2);
end;
/

drop type t_it;
drop type it;
```

Here you can see the problem that you must create global types, and this is what I hate it for. But they say in Oracle 12 it can be done with locally defined types so I am waiting for it :)

The output is:

```
Berlin, Oslo, Paris, Rome
Paris, Rome, Oslo, Berlin
```

**EDIT**

As far as you do not know the amount of iterations from the beginning the only way is to do extend on each iteration (this is only example of extending):

```
declare
  iterator       pls_integer := 1;
begin
  /* some type of loop*/ loop
    t.extend();

    -- one way to assign
    t(t.last) := new it(1,'Oslo',40);

    -- another way is to use some integer iterator
    t(iterator) := new it(1,'Oslo',40);

    iterator := iterator + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

I prefer the second way because it is faster (does not calculate `.last` on each iteration).

Comment: Wonderful reply, thank you! Is there any way to create the type within my PL/SQL function? I have to create it separately first?

Comment: Also, as I'm looping, I can't use t.extend(4). What is the best way to do this in a loop structure, just call t.extend(1) each iteration?

Comment: Yes, you have to do create global type, it is a restriction for using it in queries in 11g. I updated the answer about looping.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of pure PL/SQL implementation that is based on the idea associative array (aka map or dictionary in other domains) is an ordered collection that is sorted by a key. That is a powerful feature that I have used multiple times. For input data structure in this example I decided to use a nested table of records (aka a list of records).

In this particular case however I'd probably go for similar implementation than in simon's answer.

```
create or replace package so36 is
  -- input data structures
  type rec_t is record (
    iter number,
    str varchar2(20),
    int number
  );

  type rec_list_t is table of rec_t;

  function to_str(p_list in rec_list_t, p_sort in varchar2 default 'S')
  return varchar2;
end;
/
show errors

create or replace package body so36 is
  function to_str(p_list in rec_list_t, p_sort in varchar2 default 'S')
  return varchar2 is
    v_sep constant varchar2(2) := ', ';
    v_ret varchar2(32767);
  begin
    if p_sort = 'S' then
      -- create associative array (map) v_map where key is rec_t.str
      -- this means the records are sorted by rec_t.str
      declare
        type map_t is table of rec_t index by varchar2(20);
        v_map map_t;
        v_key varchar2(20);
      begin
        -- populate the map
        for i in p_list.first .. p_list.last loop
          v_map(p_list(i).str) := p_list(i);
        end loop;

        v_key := v_map.first;

        -- generate output string
        while v_key is not null loop
          v_ret := v_ret || v_map(v_key).str || v_sep;
          v_key := v_map.next(v_key);
        end loop;
      end;
    elsif p_sort = 'I' then
      -- this branch is identical except the associative array's key is
      -- rec_t.int and thus the records are sorted by rec_t.int
      declare
        type map_t is table of rec_t index by pls_integer;
        v_map map_t;
        v_key pls_integer;
      begin
        for i in p_list.first .. p_list.last loop
          v_map(p_list(i).int) := p_list(i);
        end loop;

        v_key := v_map.first;

        while v_key is not null loop
          v_ret := v_ret || v_map(v_key).str || v_sep;
          v_key := v_map.next(v_key);
        end loop;
      end;
    end if;

    return rtrim(v_ret, v_sep);
  end;
end;
/
show errors

declare
  v_list so36.rec_list_t := so36.rec_list_t();
  v_item so36.rec_t;
begin
  v_item.iter := 1;
  v_item.str := 'Oslo';
  v_item.int := 40;

  v_list.extend(1);
  v_list(v_list.last) := v_item;

  v_item.iter := 2;
  v_item.str := 'Berlin';
  v_item.int := 74;

  v_list.extend(1);
  v_list(v_list.last) := v_item;

  v_item.iter := 3;
  v_item.str := 'Rome';
  v_item.int := 25;

  v_list.extend(1);
  v_list(v_list.last) := v_item;

  v_item.iter := 4;
  v_item.str := 'Paris';
  v_item.int := 10;

  v_list.extend(1);
  v_list(v_list.last) := v_item;

  dbms_output.put_line(so36.to_str(v_list));
  dbms_output.put_line(so36.to_str(v_list, 'I'));
end;
/
show errors
```