# Why am I hitting a limit when using XMLAGG with an associative array?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, associative-array

Note, my question was too long, so I have pasted the code [here](http://pastebin.com/8pNxLYih).

This is on Oracle 11gR2. This question involves using XMLAGG to concatenate output from a query run on an associative array. 
It's a follow on from two other questions I asked recently: [Is Oracle's EXTRACT function breaking the NOENTITYESCAPING in the XMLELEMENT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683423/is-oracles-extract-function-breaking-the-noentityescaping-in-the-xmlelement) and [What data structure to use in order to sort this data in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177780/what-data-structure-to-use-in-order-to-sort-this-data-in-pl-sql)

If you run the code in the paste bin link above, you'll get the wonderful **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error**, but if you comment out the line beginning with **sorting_table(578)**, the code runs fine (returning a very long concatenated string). Clearly it's hit some kind of internal Oracle limit, but I'm puzzled as to what it is. My understanding was that all the data types involved here are CLOBS, is that incorrect? What's the recommended workaround?

```
select xmlagg(xmlelement(e,stringval, valueSeparator).extract('//text()') order by upper(intval)).GetClobVal()
  into lv_value
  from table(sorting_table);
```

Comment: It worked for me on 11gR1.  Strange.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use an `OBJECT TYPE` and `NESTED TABLE` instead of putting all into a *simple* table?

Comment: @Wernfried, it's explained in the linked questions. But it's not actually a nested table.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, thank you, that's very useful to know. I must try and find a 11gR1 release to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the good news is, this is not caused by the SQL: it's the subsequent DBMS_OUTPUT call which is failing, as it runs when the line is commented out:

```
589
590       -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('lv_value='||lv_value);
591*     END;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> @monster_xml
    DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 590

SQL>
```

Now, according to the docs, the [maximum line size is 32767](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#ARPLS67306).  I corrected the DBMS_OUTPUT call to show the length of your string and it's just within that:

```
SQL>  @monster_xml
lv_value=32707

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So it looks like you may be running into a Oracle bug in DBMS_OUTPUT in 11gR2.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! It never occurred to me that the DBMS_OUTPUT might be the problem. Thanks again.