# PL/SQL - Sorting collection of nested custom objects

Tags: database, oracle, sorting, plsql, user-defined-types

I am trying to sort a collection of nested custom objects. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177780/what-data-structure-to-use-in-order-to-sort-this-data-in-pl-sql) and it helped me understand how to sort a simple table of objects.

I simplified it as much as possible. In the application each of the following is a complex object with dozens of properties. For the purpose of this question, let's assume I have a table of row objects, each of these has a property that is a table of column objects:

```
create or replace TYPE myCOLUMN AS OBJECT (
    fvalue        NUMBER
);

create or replace TYPE myCOLUMNS AS TABLE OF myCOLUMN;

create or replace TYPE myROW AS OBJECT (
    cols          myCOLUMNS
);

create or replace TYPE myROWS AS TABLE OF myROW;
```

My final goal is to be able to sort this collection or rows by several columns.

```
declare
  rows        myROWS := myROWS();
begin
  rows.extend(2);
  rows(1) := new myROW(new myCOLUMNS(
    new myCOLUMN(1), new myCOLUMN(2)
  ));
  rows(2) := new myROW(new myCOLUMNS(
    new myCOLUMN(1), new myCOLUMN(1)
  ));

  -- assuming I want to order by the first and second column in ascending order
  -- the second row should be first after the sorting
end;
/
```

I am curious, whether I need to implement it from scratch or can I somehow benefit from using SQL in PL/SQL code to sort it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What you described - temporary table fits here perfectly. Have you considered it?

Comment: @Ychdziu I don't quite understand, what you mean by a temporary table. I tried to apply the approach from the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177780/what-data-structure-to-use-in-order-to-sort-this-data-in-pl-sql) I linked, but I can't readjust it to suit my needs (nested tables of objects). Can you please, elaborate or provide an example? (:

Answer (score 1):

Live by the motto - "keep it simple". The provided "solution" is based on these assumptions:

- You are using oracle DB;
- You need data structure like a table;
- You need it only on the session(user) level;
- Need sorting or other "tricks" to be done;

You could use [Global temporary table](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables).

Example:

```
create global temporary table my_temp_table (
  id number,
  name varchar2(3),
  description varchar2(20))
on commit delete rows;
```

You can populate it easily like common table:

```
begin
  insert into
    my_temp_table
  select
    tmp_data.*
  from(
    select 1, 'GBL', 'Global' from dual union
    select 2, 'TMP', 'Temporary' from dual union
    select 3, 'TBL', 'Table' from dual) tmp_data;
end;
```

Use it freely(sorted,transformed,aggregated and etc):

```
select
  tmp.id,
  tmp.name,
  tmp.description
from
  my_temp_table tmp
order by
  tmp.name
```

Only downside - the structure itself has to be defined(not dynamical). But that can be easily worked-around.

**UPDATE**

Tried to stick with your collection structure and use CAST(MULTISET()) feature, but had no luck - your current build of collection are too complex for SQL to handle. If you are still willing to stick with your approach - you can read it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators006.htm). What are you building - its pure table - why try to invent the wheel again(Keep it simple)? As I understand, why you chose this approach - the column count can change? Lets try to use earlier provided solution to your case.

So, lets say, the column count changes - still, there has to be a limit. So, lets make that max column count can be 10. Could be less, we don't care. The type of value will be number(as in your example). So, the structure will be:

```
create global temporary table my_temp_table (
  row_number number,
  column1 number,
  column2 number,
  column3 number,
  column4 number,
  column5 number,
  column6 number,
  column7 number,
  column8 number,
  column9 number,
  column10 number)
on commit delete rows;
```

Of course, now the question is HOW do you get your data. Lets say, you generate somewhere(as in your example). We fill the data:

```
begin
  insert into
    my_temp_table(
      row_number,
      column1,
      column2)
  select
    tmp_data.*
  from(
    select 
      1 row_number, 
      1 column1, 
      2 column2
    from dual 
    union
    select 
      2 ron_number, 
      1 column1, 
      1 column2
    from dual) tmp_data;
end;
```

Now, the question is WHAT you want to do with the data? Use it in calculations? Just to generate some sort report(XML) ordered? Lets say, you just want to show the output:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Sorted data');
  for l_rec in(
    select
      tmp.row_number,
      tmp.column1,
      tmp.column2
    from
      my_temp_table tmp
    order by
      tmp.column1,
      tmp.column2)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Row number: '||l_rec.row_number);
    dbms_output.put_line('Column values: '||l_rec.column1 || ', ' ||l_rec.column2);
  end loop;
end;
```

You can use this table every way you want, just keep in mind - the data is obtained only in current open session(if you use commit/rollback somewhere - the data will be lost also).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm still struggling with this. I can't manage to apply this solution to the structures I described in the question. How can I sort myROWS by the fvalues from myCOLUMN? How can I "put the rows back in the variable" in the sorted order?

Comment: Could you provide sample data? What data have you got and what result do you expect to get? With example is much easier to provide solution.

Comment: sample data is already in my question. I want to sort these 2 rows from the question by the first and second myCOLUMN fvalue. So they should swap places after successful sorting.

Comment: thank you, it is that complex, because as I said in the question these types have dozens of attributes, member procedures, etc. so it's not a pure table as you mentioned (I only simplified it for the purposes of the question). I need to reorder the rows and store them back, I was curious if I can use SQL to handle that, but it's just too complex and I need to implement a custom sort in PL/SQL right?

Comment: I'm afraid yes - you will have to implement custom sorting algorithm. There are already tons of methods(bubble sort, heap sort and etc), how to sort them (even written in PL/SQL by other people). Just need to find the optimal for your case. You could write a stored procedure, where it gets your collection as in/out parameter and do all the logic there.