# Sum of Associate array values in PL/SQL

Tags: arrays, plsql, sum

Is there any way to have sum of values of associate array in PL/SQL. normally the code is like this:

```
    FOR i IN a.FIRST .. a.LAST
     LOOP
        IF a (i).weight > 0
        THEN
           flag := FALSE;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
```

but it should be a way to do it without loop and using sum.

something like:

```
 IF SUM(a.weight) > 0
 THEN
     flag := FALSE;
 END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually - normally the code above is wrong for looping through associative arrays. Try this.

```
declare
   type t_array_rec is record(
      weight number);
   type t_array is table of t_array_rec index by pls_integer;
   arr t_array;
   li_idx int;
   li_summ int := 0;
begin
   arr(1).weight := 100;
   arr(3).weight:= 200;
   arr(5).weight := 150;

   li_idx := arr.first;
   while (li_idx is not null) loop
      li_summ := li_summ + nvl(arr(li_idx).weight, 0);          
      li_idx := arr.next(li_idx);
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line(li_summ);
end;
```

This will count the min value. Also You can kindly have a look at the another answer on SO [sorting the assotiative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800880/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-in-pl-sql) .

In case of nested tables, You can use the [table functions.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm#i454908)
Assuming You have the TTI type on the database layer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TTI as table of int
```

You can aggragate it's values like shown bellow

```
declare   
   arr TTI := TTI(100, 200, 150);
   li_summ number;
begin
   select sum(column_value) into li_summ from table(arr);
   dbms_output.put_line(li_summ);
end;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Ignoring the way of looping, what I am looking for is to have the sum of values. lets say, a(1).weight := 1; and a(2).weight :=3. is there any way to have the sum of these values (in example here will be 4) without loop?

Comment: I updated my answer, to make the block calculating the sum instead of max. For the associative arrays You don't have any option like the table functions for the nested tables, the only way is the looping through the array.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am able to use the updated version while my concern is to sum the weight value. so the code will be something like this: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `declare
   type t_array_rec is record(
      weight number);
   type t_array is table of t_array_rec index by pls_integer;
   arr t_array;
   li_idx int;
   li_summ int := 0;
begin
   arr(1).weight := 100;
   arr(2).weight:= 200;
   arr(3).weight := 150;

   select sum(column_value) into li_summ from table(arr.weight);
   dbms_output.put_line(li_summ);
end;`