# Sorting an index-by table (associative array)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to sort an associative array defined as a "table of number index by binary_integer". I can code a quick sort algorithm by hand, but surely there must be a way to sort my values **using a query (order by)** ?

Illustration of my problem :

*Definition of my associative array type:*

```
create or replace package my_type is 
   type my_array is table of NUMBER index by binary_integer;
end my_type ;
```

*For testing purposes, let's generate a test array with values that or not sorted in ascending order.*

```
declare
  test my_array.my_type.;
  i number := 10;

begin
  while (i > 0) loop
       test(10 - i) :=  i;
       i := i - 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

*I would like to sort this array in ascending order, using a query with an ORDER BY. Something along those lines :*

```
  i := 0;
  for query_result_row in (select 1 as val from table(test) order by 1) loop
     test(i) := query_result_row.val;
     i := i + 1;
  end loop;
```

This approach should be possible : "Oracle 12c supports querying associative arrays using the TABLE operator, as long as the type is declared in a package spec: https://galobalda.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/new-in-oracle-12c-querying-an-associative-array-in-plsql-programs/ "

I suspect that the problem comes from the way I select the column with ordinals. It isn't possible apparently, but there is no column name (as it is an associative array), so I'm stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an associative array in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800880/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-in-pl-sql)

Comment: No, the answer given is not the one I am looking for, I want to query associative arrays using the TABLE operator. Converting everything to another collection is not what I am looking for: if that was absolutely required, i would be better off with a hand-coded quickSort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Querying associative arrays using the TABLE operator worked. As I though, the issue was coming from the column selection, it doesn't work with ordinals. For an an associative array that went though the table operator, the column name to select is COLUMN_VALUE.

**Completed solution:**

Definition of my associative array type:

```
create or replace package my_type is 
   type my_array is table of NUMBER index by binary_integer;
end my_type ;
```

Generating a test array with values that or not sorted in ascending order and sorting them:

```
declare
  test my_array.my_type.;
  i number := 10;

begin
  -- Generating a test array with values that or not sorted in asc order
  while (i > 0) loop
       test(10 - i) :=  i;
       i := i - 1;
  end loop;

-- Sorting the values :
for query_result_row in (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE from table(test) order by 1) loop
   i := i + 1;
   test(i) = query_result_row.COLUMN_VALUE;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even save yourself some of the assignment lines of code using BULK COLLECT:

```sql
DECLARE
  test my_array.my_type;
  i number := 10;
  CURSOR c IS
    SELECT t.column_value
    FROM table(test) t
    ORDER BY t.column_value;
begin
  -- Generating a test array with values that or not sorted in asc order
  while (i > 0) loop
       test(10 - i) :=  i;
       i := i - 1;
  end loop;

  OPEN c;
  FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO test;
  CLOSE c;
END;
```

Note: You can't just write a SELECT with BULK COLLECT INTO.  It appears that Oracle empties out the collection before the statement is run.  You don't get an error, but you also don't get any results.